# How suppress "property" prefix on Sphinx-doc autodoc entries for a property

Tags: python-sphinx

In my most recent Sphinx run to generate the documentation for the `python-pptx` project I'm getting a *property* prefix in front of each property defined on each class.

That's annoying because almost all the items on a given class are properties and it doesn't really tell the reader anything interesting, just makes the interface attributes (properties, methods) not line up. I use the parentheses-on-functions option so methods are clearly distinct from properties without having to be all (redundantly) explicit about it.

It never used to do that, but this is probably the first time I've generated under Python 3 and using Sphinx 4.2. I tried searching on `sphinx suppress property prefix` and similar but didn't come up with anything at all.

How do I shut that off so it generates the same way it used to? Here's an example of how it used to look:
[image]

and this is what it's looking like now:
[image]

Comment: What version of Sphinx was used to generate the old output without "property"?

Comment: @mzjn at the bottom of the page it says "Created using Sphinx 1.8.5". Not sure how that squares with the `Sphinx==4.0.1` I get on `pip freeze` for the new one that adds the prefix. That seems like a big jump.

Comment: The "property" prefix was added in this commit AFAICT: https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/blame/ba2439a105e5a68a44dd3f839e86332889cce451/sphinx/domains/python.py#L748

Comment: Looking at the code that @mzjn shared, I'd say this is not possible.

Comment: Yeah, that's my reading too, naive as my reading is. Thanks to you both mzjn and astrojuanlu for your help :)